# Modificar os indices de cada item em um TreeView Java FX ou sobreecrever método TreeView.getSelectionModel().select(int index)?

Tags: java, javafx, índices, treeview, sobrescrita

Saudações à todos. Este é meu primeiro post aqui.

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto Java FX que consite de um formulário com um TreeView cujos itens são obtidos de um ArrayList, preenchido anteriormente através de uma consulta ao banco de dados.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa tabela representa uma hierarquia de items onde cada item possui um id, nome e um parent_id (id de outro item da tabela, tido como pai do item em questão).

Para montar árvore estou usando um foreach para selecionar o item na árvore cujo id corresponde ao parent_id (c.getParent) de cada item a ser adicionado :

```
for (Conta c : list){
    try {
        tree.getSelectionModel().select(c.getParent());

        MyTreeItem item = (MyTreeItem)tree.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        item.setExpanded(true);

        MyTreeItem conta = new MyTreeItem (c.getNome(),c.getId());
        item.getChildren().add(conta);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Esse método funcionou conforme eu esperava:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando executei o  projeto na primeira vez a tabela já possuia os registros e a árvore foi montada corretamente. Depois implementei métodos para adicionar filhos a qualquer nó selecionado pelo usuário. O problema é que percebi que, embora o método esteja salvando o novo item corretamente no BD (vide imagem abaixo), se eu atualizar a árvore, ou fechar e abrir o programa novamente, a árvore irá mostrar o item recém adicionado como filho de um item diferente do que tinha sido escolhido e que é apontado pelo campo parente_id como pai.

[image: Itens recém criados no BD]

Note que o item "Conta corrente 6666"(parent_id = 15) deveria ser filho da conta "Bank of Boston"(id = 15)

[image: Items recém criados no sistema]

Então eu criei um TreeItem personalizado com os parâmetros id e nome para, na hora de montar a árvore tentar organizar a hierarquia usando como critério o id que o elemento representado na árvore tem no banco. Foi então que percebi que o problema está nessa linha: `tree.getSelectionModel().select(c.getParent());` pois ela seleciona o item pelo index no Treeview, só que este index não corresponde ao id do elemento no banco.

**Minha dúvida é como faço para que a linha de código `tree.getSelectionModel().select(int index);` selecione um item em um TreeView não pelo parâmetro index (posição do item no TreeView(?)), mas usando como parametro o identificador (int id) que eu criei numa classe derivada de TreeItem com este atributo.**

Grato à todos desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz um pouco diferente da sua proposta e pra mim funcionou corretamente, vou explicar passo a passo como eu fiz:

```
List<TreeItem<Conta>> treeItems = new ArrayList<>();

// Criando todos os tree itens
for (Conta c: contas) {
    TreeItem<Conta> newItem = new TreeItem<Conta>(c);
    treeItems.add(newItem);
}

// Adicionando filhos dos nós
for (TreeItem<Conta> no : treeItems) {
    // Pega o id do nó
    int id = no.getValue().getId();

    // Busca os nós que tem como parentId o id do pai
    List<TreeItem<Conta>> filhos = treeItems.stream()
                .filter( filho -> filho.getValue().getParent_id() == id)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

    // Adiciona-os como filhos
    no.getChildren().setAll(filhos);
}

// Adiciona o nó root na árvore 
TreeView<Conta> tree = new TreeView<>(treeItems.get(0));
```

Primeiro eu criei todos os TreeItems a partir do array de contas, e só então eu fui navegando pelos nós criados e adicionando os filhos. Até aqui não sei se está muito diferente mas não sei se você percebeu que **TreeItem** aceita um tipo através de Generics.

Obs.: Para que o nome do objeto no TreeView não fique estranho você tem que sobrescrever o método toString da classe conta dessa forma:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return nome; // Vai retornar apenas o nome do objeto como representação
}
```

Para adicionar novos nós eu fiz o seguinte:

```
Button adicionarNo = new Button("Adicionar nó");
adicionarNo.setOnAction((ActionEvent) -> {
    // Pega uma referência ao item selecionado ao invés de usar o Index
    TreeItem<Conta> itemSelecionado = tree.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

    // Verifica se a seleção não está vazia, para evitar NPE
    if(itemSelecionado != null) {
        int idpai = itemSelecionado.getValue().getId();

        // Adiciona a conta no banco de dados,
        // Aqui você pode retornar o id da nova conta criada no banco
        int idconta = 0; //adicionaConta("Nome do item", idpai);

        TreeItem<Conta> novoItem = new TreeItem<Conta>(new Conta(idconta, idpai, "Nome do item"));
        itemSelecionado.getChildren().add(novoItem);
   }
});
```

Dessa forma consegui criar novos nós em qualquer lugar da árvore sem problemas.

Comment: Fiz um novo projeto e acrecentei o seu código em substituição ao que estava usando. Executei a aplicação e aparentemente deu certo exceto porque os itens da árvore estão exibindo os endereços de memória dos objetos(acho que é isso)[![Try_FX.png](https://s6.postimg.cc/qdw7cu7n5/Try_FX.png)](https://postimg.cc/image/vcjprdbfx/). Como eu faço para exibir na arvore só o nome da conta? Tentei algo como "no.getChildren().setAll(filhos);" ou "treeItems.add(newItem.getValue());"  mas não consegui... Alguma dica?

Comment: Poxa, esqueci de citar este detalhe. Sempre que usamos objetos temos que dizer como ele vai ser representado sobrescrevendo o método toString. Irei alterar a resposta.

Comment: Muito bom! Segui sua orientação e sobreescrevi o toString, depois implementei os métodos SQL necessarios para inserir os novos items da arvore no BD e acrescentei à lógica que você usou para o botão de adicionar. Seguindo o mesmo raciocínio fiz também um botão/método para remover os itens da árvore e do banco. Funcionou perfeitamente.Muito obrigado.